# Exe compiled with dev c++ won't close

Tags: c++

Yesterday i was coding on Dev C++ and when compiled the .exe would not run. I closed everything and opened again and Dev gave me a return 1 error. I moved the files on another drive everything worked just fine but i could not delete the first ones on my desktop. I now have 4 processes on task manager named with the .exe file that give access denied when trying to end them and i can't delete the file. Also restart did nothing processes still there.
Please help,
Thank you!

Comment: You're saying you rebooted your entire computer and yet the processes are still running?

Comment: Yes i restarted my computer twice and the f*cking thing is still open.

Comment: I named the file dp.exe (from dinamic programing) i don't know if there is a proccess on windows that is named this way and my computer think it shouldn't be close or smth

Comment: taskkill /f /id dp.exe returns ERROR: The process "dp.exe" with PID 3820 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
ERROR: The process "dp.exe" with PID 8828 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

Comment: Try to rename your project.... I suppose, `dp.exe` that cannot be stopped can be a malware

Comment: That's not a C++ question *at all*.

Comment: I know it's not C++ but what should i tag it with?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I renamed the file restarted my computer and it worked... managed to delete the file for good (the 35 passes gutman way, none will ever be able to get my deadly dp demonstration again). Thanks to VolAnd for suggesting!